# Is it possible to dequeue a message from SQS AWS service even before it gets processed?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I just started using SQS service of AWS. Well, I do know that we can delete a process using its `ReceiptHandle` that we get when we receive a message but I want to delete a message when it is in a queue or move it to the dead letter queue.
Is it possible because there is no mention of it in the documentation? If yes can you please provide me a hint or code or any link to it.
Thanks

Like there is this method which uses `ReceiptHandle` to delete a message.

```
for (Message m : messages) {
    sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl, m.getReceiptHandle());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot delete messages selectively without reading them you can delete all the messages in a queue at one go using the Purge Queue feature.

More details are listed at [delete-all-messages-in-an-amazon-sqs-queue](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/12/08/delete-all-messages-in-an-amazon-sqs-queue/)

And if you want to do that programmatically then the various SDKs support that as well.

[Here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.purge_queue) is an example of how to do that using the Python SDK

Answer (score 2):

Upon doing some more researching, I found this on AWS SQS developer guide.

> Every time you receive a message from a queue, you receive a receipt handle for that message. This handle is associated with the action of receiving the message, not with the message itself. To delete the message or to change the message visibility, you must provide the receipt handle (not the message ID). Thus, you must always receive a message before you can delete it (you can't put a message into the queue and then recall it). The maximum length of a receipt handle is 1,024 characters.`